# Can I edit the header bytes of a .EXE file but still retain a working program?

Tags: windows, process

As we know, exe files generally start with 4D5A or 'MZ' in ASCII. How would I change the header whilst still allowing the file to work as normal?

Right now i'm looking at ccleaner's exe file. Unfortunately i've not got 10 rep so I cannot post a screenshot of it.But the ASCII on the right says the program cannot be run in ASCII, therefore rendering the 4D5A useless? So technically, could I change the 4D5A to something else and it would still work?

If any old-school guys are on here, as much info on the 'DOS MZ' would be very much appreciated.

This is the image I was looking at:

[image: CCleaner Hex View]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I change the header whilst still allowing the file to work
>   as normal?

**You can't!**

There's a reason the `MZ` string (16-bits representing `0x5A4D`) is referred to as a "magic" number, and indeed, is required as per the EXE/PE specification (with roots all the way back to DOS-format executables).  The layout of all modern [portable executables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) appears as follows ([ref](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files#File_Format)):

[image]

In [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) regarding the Portable Executable format, the MS-DOS header is detailed:

> **The MS-DOS Header**
>
> Every PE file begins with a small MS-DOS® executable. The need for this stub executable arose in the early days
>   of Windows, before a significant number of consumers were running it.
>   When executed on a machine without Windows, the program could at least
>   print out a message saying that Windows was required to run the
>   executable.
>
> The first bytes of a PE file begin with the traditional MS-DOS header,
>   called an `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`. **The only two values of any importance are
>   `e_magic` and `e_lfanew`.** The `e_lfanew` field contains the file offset of
>   the PE header.
>
> **The `e_magic` field (a WORD *[NB: 16-bits]*) needs to be set to the value
>   `0x5A4D`. There's a `#define` for this value, named `IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE`.
>   In ASCII representation, `0x5A4D` is `MZ`, the initials of Mark Zbikowski,
>   one of the original architects of MS-DOS.**

---

For further information regarding the Windows PE/.EXE format, I highly recommend taking a look at the [Windows Executable Files section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files) of the [x86 Disassembly Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly).  It contains an extensive array of low-level information regarding the format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The x86 book looks fantastic. Will be giving it a thorough read.

Comment: @BubbleMonster I agree, that x86 Disassembly book is very useful and informative. You might also find the **[x86 Assembly Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly)** another great resource, which complements the x86 Disassembly Wikibook quite nicely.